# Character counting with a Linked List

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am trying to Design a program that reads an ASCII text file one byte at a time and outputs the frequency count of how many times each character appears.

The output does not need to be sorted. The character frequency objects need to be processed and stored using a `Linked List`.

I know that my character frequency class is okay, however I cannot figure out how to count the characters. This is the code I have so far, but my counts end up as `0`.

```
LinkedList<CharacterFrequency> list = new LinkedList<CharacterFrequency>();

CharacterFrequency cf = new CharacterFrequency();
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"input.txt");

var ch = -1;

while ((ch = file.Read ()) !=-1)
{
    LinkedListNode<CharacterFrequency> node;
    node = list.Find(cf);

    if (list.Any())
    {
        cf.Increment();

    }

    if (node != null)
    {
        list.AddLast(cf);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(cf.ToString());
file.Close();

//and here is my character frequency class;

class CharacterFrequency
{
    private Char m_char;
    private int m_count;

    public CharacterFrequency()
    {
        m_char = '\0';
        m_count = 0;
    }

    public CharacterFrequency(Char ch)
    {
        m_char = ch;
        m_count = 0;
    }

    public CharacterFrequency(Char ch, int count)
    {
        m_char = ch;
        m_count = count;
    }

    public CharacterFrequency(CharacterFrequency cf)
    {
        m_char = cf.Character;
        m_count = cf.Count;
    }

    public Char Character
    {
        get
        {
            return m_char;
        }
        set
        {
            m_char = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return m_count;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_count > value)
                m_count = value;
        }
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        m_count++;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}({1}) {2}", m_char, (int)m_char, m_count);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)m_char;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (obj == this)
            return true;

        if (!(obj.GetType() == GetType()))
            return false;

        CharacterFrequency rhs = (CharacterFrequency)obj;
        return this.Character == rhs.Character;
    }
}
```

Updated code (I have not been able to work through the issue with the increment method yet):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int ch;
        const int Input_File = 0;
        const int Output_File = 1;
        StreamReader reader = null;
        StreamWriter writer = null;

        //linked list declaration
        LinkedList<CharacterFrequency> list =
            new LinkedList<CharacterFrequency>();



        //read the characters from the input file
        reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(args[Input_File]));



        while ((ch = reader.Read ()) !=-1)//casts to integer
        {
            CharacterFrequency cf = LinkedList<CharacterFrequency>list(ch); //attempt to create linked list from character frequency BIG ISSUES HERE!

            LinkedListNode<CharacterFrequency> node; //attempt to create node
            node = list.Find(cf); // find method

            if (node != null) //increment if found
            {
                node.Value.Increment();

            }

            else //add if not found
            {
                list.AddLast(cf);
            }
        }

        reader.Close();


        //write outputfile

        writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(args[Output_File]));

        foreach (CharacterFrequency cf in list)
            writer.WriteLine(cf.ToString());
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a dictionary than a linked list? It would be much quicker to find the character entry.

Comment: @Magnus It probably would be but I have to specifically use a linked list unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is here :

```
if (list.Any())
{
     cf.Increment();

}
```

I think it should be (You may need to adjust it more):

```
if(node != null) {
   node.getData().increment();
}
else {
    list.AddLast(cf);
}
```

There's also a problem with the fact that you don't use `ch` . At the beggining of the loop, you should recreate a `LinkedListNode<CharacterFrequency> cf`  from the char you've read, or the code won't work .

**EDIT:** You can't declare a variable more than once, so simply take it outside the loop

```
 CharacterFrequency cf;
 while ((ch = reader.Read ()) !=-1)//casts to integer
    {
        cf = LinkedList<CharacterFrequency>list(ch); 
        ....
```

Comment: wont work if node is null the list.AddLast will fail

Comment: @styx Yup.. fixed, OP code is missing plenty of things.

Comment: @sagi    Thank you! that makes sense. I am running into this error: CS0136 A local or parameter named 'ch' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter......when I try to add the creation of the linked list using ch at the beginning of the loop. any ideas there?

Comment: @sagi I updated my code. There were quite a few changes and I haven't been able to work through the increment part yet. I tried to comment the best I could this time.

Comment: It maybe will complain about `cf` might not be initialized , so just intiizalize it with some dummy data before the loop instead of just declaring it .